# Appcelerator - Post a Tweet from iPhone App - Stuck on Callback URL

Tags: iphone, twitter, titanium, appcelerator, callbackurl

I am needing to send a tweet for from my iphone/ipad app using Appcelerator Titanium & javascript. I found the following example on github (code also posted below for this):

https://gist.github.com/2eabc31db388144b3abc

I have created my app details (key,secret etc) in my twitter developer account and using the code from the example i get the twitter login and authorisation popup but once you click authorise, all i get is a webview showing the callback url (that i was required to put in the twitter app settings). So the app is stuck on a webview showing the callback url but does nothing after. If i close the popup window it just goes back to my app without sending a tweet.

Can anyone help?

code in app.js:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor: '#fff' });
var shareButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width: 90, bottom: 10, height: 30,
    title: 'Tweet!"'
});
win.add(shareButton);
win.open();

var social = require('social');
var twitter = social.create({
    site: 'Twitter',
    consumerKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
    consumerSecret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' 
});

shareButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    twitter.share({
        message: 'Hello, world!',
        success: function() {
            alert('Tweeted!');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert('Oh no! ' + error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is this the same question from the QA Forums? Dont want to be conversing with you in both places?

Comment: Hi Aaron, yes it is. Thanks for your help in there. It's all sorted now :)

Answer (score 1):

As [Aaron answered on the Q&A](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/142880/post-a-tweet-from-iphone-app---stuck-on-callback-url), when using Social.js, you should not use a callback URL. The [code itself will watch the web view](https://gist.github.com/00e95c5d95d2b7d5d027#L991) for what it needs.